# Can you populate a UITableView without using the cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Tags: uitableview, swift, dictionary

The reason I ask is because I have a Dictionary of objects that I would like to populate my UITableView with. Since the Dictionary has objects for both the key and value, I'm unsure of how to populate the UITableView with it. The only way I know of to populate a UITableView is to use cellForRowAtIndexPath which requires an index (indexPath.row) and since my Dictionary is a collection of objects, I'm unable to reference each object by index.

Does anyone know if you can populate a UITableView without using cellForRowAtIndexPath method? Or, is there a way to populate the UITableView with the Dictionary of object by using cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Dictionaries do not have a fixed order, so this would possibly yield different results on each run of the app. Convert the dictionary to an array of tuples of the key/value pairs first.

Comment: I've added an answer with code to help you to do this! :) (Note the ordering difference between initialising the dictionary and the resultant array!)

Comment: As we are living in an object oriented world, consider to use a custom class or struct as model rather than quasi generic collection classes like dictionary or tuple. Basically it's possible to populate a table view without `cellForRowAtIndexPath` however then you have to use static cells.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment:

> Dictionaries do not have a fixed order, so this would possibly yield different results on each run of the app.

So convert the dictionary to an array of the key/value tuples.
To convert a dictionary to an array (substitute your correct types as appropriate):

```
let dictionary = ["a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3]
var array = [(String, Int)]()

for tuple in dictionary {
    array.append(tuple)
}

println(array)
```

Outputs:

```
[(b, 2), (a, 1), (c, 3)]
```